# Unable to pass vector to lambda function

Tags: c++, c++17

Im unable to pass my vector into my lambda function.

Am i missing something simple?

Thanks.

```
std::vector<Wnd_S> GetWindows()
{
    std::vector<Wnd_S> vRet;

    ::EnumWindows(static_cast<WNDENUMPROC>([vRet](HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL {

        char buffer[255];
        GetClassNameA(hWnd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        if (std::string(buffer) == "Wnd" ||
            std::string(buffer) == "Wnd2")
            vRet.push_back({ hWnd, buffer });

        return TRUE;

        }), 0);

    return vRet;
}
```

Comment: State lambda cannot be casted to function pointer. You should allocate your vector by new, then pass this pointer as lParam argument.

Comment: @rafix07 If `EnumWindows` is synchronous (looks like it from the docs) you can still allocate the vector on the stack and pass a pointer to that; no need to use `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capturing lambdas cannot be casted into function pointers, so you can't capture `vRet`. But `EnumWindows` takes the second parameter that is then passed to the callback function. You can use it to pass `vRet` into your callback:

```
std::vector<Wnd_S> GetWindows() {
    std::vector<Wnd_S> vRet;

    ::EnumWindows([](HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL {
        auto& vRet = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<Wnd_S>*>(lParam);
           // ...
    }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&vRet));

    return vRet;
}
```